# Why are there only human males at the Battle of Yavin?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

I was watching *A New Hope* and I just realized something; when General Jan Dodonna was briefing everyone for the Death Star assault, the only pilots assembled are male humans. No female humans or aliens. Why is this?

I know the [Doylist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Doylist) answer is that it was 1977 and women faced sexism in every industry and making alien costumes for pilots might've been just a bit too expensive, but in-universe, what's the explanation for this?

The Empire was xenophobic, so all their troops and officers were human, but the Rebel Alliance was open to all races.

Comment: Hera was a member of the Rebellion: https://starwarsrebels.fandom.com/wiki/Hera_Syndulla

Comment: The rebellion was open to all races, but they might not have been evenly distributed across all rebel bases. Had the death star approached Mon Cala, the pilot rooster might have looked different.

Comment: Casting, and special effects costs :D

Comment: @EikePierstorff:  Pilot ***rooster***?   I thought we established there weren't alien pilots?

Comment: @ThePopMachine I am an alien (in all countries but one anyway) so forgive my lapse in language (alas I am German, I guess it would be funnier if I was French).

Comment: Real world explanation: probably just passive mid-to-late 70's casting prejudice. Put out a call to Equity for extras to play "Generals" and "Fighter Pilots", and they'd go through the rolodex and send you a bunch of older and younger male actors respectively. Sending in women for the call probably didn't even occur to them at the time.

Comment: Maybe all the alien female pilots died at the battle of Scarif? After all, they had an X-Wing available for a farm boy who’d never flown before.

Comment: In-universe, having human males would be realistic, humans are the most common species in the star wars galaxy and males make up the bulk of combatants in any war. If anything the later additions of female pilots is the unrealistic part. About 99,999% of all combat pilots in the world are male, even in countries like Israel where women are allowed to serve as front line combat pilots its very unusual. Women served as bomber crews in Russia during WWII, but they were the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: One thing to consider for the *alien* part of the question is that the craft design requires a humanoid pilot within a specific height and mass range, and with hands and fingers. So some species simply wouldn't be practical as pilots for the equipment available.

Answer (score 13):

There were not only male humans at the Battle of Yavin. Additional canon commentary (written since the film was shown) has revealed that several human *females* were involved in the battle also, including;

- [**Evaan Verlaine**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gold_Squadron_(Rebel_Alliance)#:%7E:text=A%20New%20Hope%20%2D%20The%20Film%20Novel%20establishes%20that%20only%20one%20Y%2Dwing%20starfighter%20remained%20by%20the%20time%20the%20Death%20Star%20was%20destroyed%2C%20and%20Princess%20Leia%201%20states%20that%20the%20surviving%20Y%2Dwing%20was%20piloted%20by%20Evaan%20Verlaine.%20Therefore%2C%20it%20must%20have%20been%20Verlaine%27s%20Y%2Dwing%20that%20Versio%20targeted.) - Gold Squadron (Survived)

> [image]

and

- [**Zal Dinnes**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zal_Dinnes) - Red Squadron (KIA)

> [image]

- [**Iden Versio**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Iden_Versio) - Black Squadron (Imperial) (Survived)
  [image]
- [**Jaldine Gerams**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jaldine_Gerams) and [**Wona Goban**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wona_Goban?so=search) may also have participated as they were not seen dying on screen in Rogue One and were confirmed (via the *Rogue One: Visual Guide*) to have been members of Gold Squadron.

---

In other (now non-canon) works, we see an array of other female pilots;

- [**Ru Murleen**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ru_Murleen) (Survived)
- [**Shara**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shara) (Survived - Was piloting a support ship, not a fighter)
- Another [**unnamed female pilot**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_female_X-wing_pilot_(Yavin)) shown in a trading card published in 2010.

Comment: Coming soon to scifi: Why were there only blonde human females at the Battle of Yavin?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - clearly because all the radiation in space bleaches hair white. Only the men are concerned about their looks and dye it back to dark...

Comment: @JonCuster "Peacocking" is a verb for a reason.

Comment: Might also be worth noting that on the Imperial side we have Iden Versio flying with Black Squadron, and surviving (seemingly while attempting to chase down Verlaine.)

Comment: @Kris - Her [CV](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Iden_Versio) is appalling. She was involved in every Imperial and First Order screw-up we saw on screen. I wouldn't be surprised if she wasn't moonlighting as one of the stormtroopers who let the droids escape.

Comment: @Valorum I'd say surviving one Imperial military farce is a sign of a very lucky fighter. Surviving several? Well that's just pure skill! Also in her defence; once she switched sides, she was actively trying to screw up those Imperial & First Order's operations. ;)

Comment: Because although the female pilots could fly the X-wings, they couldn't park them when they got back? <ducks and runs>